# Navigation stack, local_planner and odometry: covariance all zeros ok?

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

We're just getting started tuning the navigation stack for [this](https://projects.cecs.pdx.edu/projects/roboticsclub-mcecsbot/wiki) robot. We're publishing odometry as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom), and so far, so good. I'm confused about something though: in the code, we're broadcasting nav_msgs/Odometry messages without setting the covariances (i.e. they're all zeros).

My question: is this the correct thing to do?

Thanks in advance,

Rick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157181/navigation-stack,-local_planner-and-odometry:-covariance-all-zeros-ok?/) by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 567 on 2014-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on what you're doing with those messages. If you have another node that just needs the odometry information (like rviz), then the covariances are superfluous. If you want to fuse that data with other sources, then most algorithms will require the covariances to be non-zero. You may also be interested in having that information for debugging purposes.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2014-05-07**:
Thanks, Tom.